# SELECT-OPTIONS translation is not active when created via ADT

Tags: abap, dynpro, sap-selection-screens

I created a program with following `SELECT-OPTIONS` using eclipse with ADT logon language `EN`.

```
DATA: hkont TYPE hkont,
      bukrs TYPE bukrs,
      gjahr TYPE bseg-gjahr.

SELECT-OPTIONS: s_bukrs FOR bukrs,
                s_hkont FOR hkont,
                s_gjahr FOR gjahr.
```

When maintaining the text elements and referencing the select-options with their DDIC Reference in English everything is looking fine.

[image: English]

Also in German everything looks ok in the selection text maintaining screen.

[image: German]

When starting the program the English Selection Screen looking fine but for German the selection texts are not displayed in German.

English:

[image: English2]

German:

[image: German2]

I would expect that the DDIC reference text in German is also displayed in the Selection Screen when running the program.

Did someone of you has experienced a similar issue and how do you solve it?

---

What I tried so far:

- rename the select-options
- copy into another program
- remove the DDIC reference and translating it with goto -> translation and rechecking the DDIC reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that I had to go into translations and save there one more time.
[image]

This will copy the translations from the dictionary.